# Bulk Insert CSV to Table with Identity Column using SQL Server 2008R2 Web

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I have a CSV file that I would like to bulk insert into a table that has the exact same columns as the target table, *except* that the target table also has an identity column as the primary key.  The CSV file lacks that identity column.

Reading MSDN, I must use the FORMATFILE parameter if

> The data file contains greater or fewer columns than the table or view

and states

> A format file describes the data file that contains stored responses created by using the bcp utility

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Is "bcp" the same thing as the SQL Server Import/Export wizard?  If not, where can I find it?

I note that SQL Server Import/Export wizard does not allow the import rules to be saved in the Express, Web or Workgroup editions.  If that is indeed the tool I am supposed to use to build the FORMATFILE, do I have any options?

Is there a different/better way than using a FORMATFILE to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0):

Well, to answer one question, BCP is a command line tool which you will find in the bin directory of the installation. BCP is able to insert a lot data the fast way, it is a bulkcopy program. To be able to keep the identity column intact you can you use the -E parameter.

However, you will have to use a formatfile, which you can create the BCP utility!